# gnuplot: stacked newhistogram, starting with same fillstyle pattern, not appearing in shared key

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram

I am trying to create multiple columnstacked histograms in gnuplot using the newhistogram command. 
The data share the same structure so I want the boxes to share the **same key** like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483006/gnuplot-multiple-stacked-histograms-each-group-using-the-same-key), but with a **pattern fillstyle** (not only color).

My script looks like this:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill pattern
set boxwidth 0.75
set xtics ("fff" 0, "ggg" 1, "hhh" 3, "iii" 4)
set grid y
set border 3 # remove top and right plot-border

set key outside title 'key' width -30

plot \
newhistogram "data A" fs pattern 2 lt 1, \
"plot_test_data.out" u 2, '' u 3, \
newhistogram "data B" fs pattern 2 lt 1, \
"plot_test_data_2.out" u 2:key(1), '' u 3
```

which produces the following output:

[image: columnstacked histograms]

Could anybody explain why the key doesn't show the correct pattern? (I tried adding fs pattern in each using directive and removing the linetype, but nothing bears the desired output).

I am using

G N U P L O T
Version 4.6
patchlevel 3
last modified 2013-04-12
Build System: Linux x86_64

with 2 test data sets

plot_test_data.out:

```
0 1 3 2 2
1 1 6 4 4 
2 2 5 4 5
3 1 1 3 4
4 1 2 4 5
```

plot_test_data_2.out:

```
0 1 4 3 1 
1 3 6 4 2 
2 2 5 6 4
3 2 5 5 3
4 1 3 4 2
```

thank you!

Comment: Which gnuplot version and patchlevel do you have? Can you please post the data set so that other can check this?

Comment: I just added the information. thank you

Comment: Your example works fine with version 4.6.5, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/PFAL8.png

Comment: I think this is a bug which was fixed in 4.6.4