# Gnuplot: increase line width of fillstyle pattern

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, fill

I have a script to make the following histogram

[image]

The plotting commands are something like

```
plot newhistogram, "size_class_data/tree_gigante.txt" using 2 lc rgb data_color title "Field data",\
newhistogram at 0.33-boxwidth/2, '' using 3:xticlabel(1) lc rgb early_color title "Early successional",\
'' using 4 lc rgb mid_color title "Mid successional",\
'' using 5 lc rgb late_color title "Late successional",\
newhistogram at 0.66-boxwidth, '' using 6 fs pattern 2 lt -1 lc rgb early_color lw 2 title "Early successional (No liana)",\
'' using 7 fs pattern 2 lt -1 lc rgb mid_color lw 2 title "Mid successional (No liana)",\
'' using 8 fs pattern 2 lt -1 lc rgb late_color lw 2 title "Late successional (No liana)"
```

If I increase `lw` what changes is the thickness of the bar borders. Is there a way to increase the thickness of the pattern lines, because it's quite hard to see the color of the filling.

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480095/gnuplot-stacked-newhistogram-starting-with-same-fillstyle-pattern-not-appeari) there is a MRE for a very similar case.

Comment: as far as I know you cannot change much with the fillstyle pattern. I recently asked about fill patterns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547501/hatch-patterns-in-gnuplot

Comment: Yes seemed kind of a dead end. I finally managed to get a decent result by using the `pdfcairo` terminal (plotting twice, one for the bar and one for the pattern with a transparent background). Kind of a workaround but it worked. Maybe some other terminal will fit other specific needs. Hope they change this in future versions though...